# How do I change the value of a textarea with a `onCopy` while putting the value of the textarea into my copy buffer

Tags: reactjs

I am currently trying to implement an onCopy handler in a textarea that changes the value of the textarea based on the onCopy event. As far as I can tell I am losing focus on my text area before the system's actual copy happens, meaning that I actually have no text selected when I am copying.

In the snippet below I am expecting "Copy the textbox" to appear in my copy buffer, instead, nothing happens. Neither the old value or the new value appear in my copy buffer.

My question isn't specifically about the copying the old value or the new value, either would be acceptable.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Copy the textbox!' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <input
          type="textarea"
          value={this.state.text}
          onCopy={() => {
            this.setState({ text: 'Copied!' });
            return true;
          }}
          onChange={() => console.log("input.onChange")}
        />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you accept solutions including `setTimeout`? :)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Copy the textbox!' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <input
          type="textarea"
          value={this.state.text}
          onCopy={() => setTimeout( () =>
            this.setState({ text: 'Copied!' }),
            100 )
          }
          onChange={() => console.log("input.onChange")}
        />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

But, it is really weird that setting the value with `setState` prevents copying. At first, I thought `setState` is the problem here but if we set another random state property we can copy the old value.

Comment: It works with a 0 timeout too, I'm assuming this means it's queued to happen after the browser has dealt with the copy event, which is precisely what I want.

Comment: I am not going to mark this as the accepted solution yet because I am hoping for a solution that "feels" safer where I don't have to worry about unintended side-effects, e.g., unmounting the component in the onCopy causing the timeout to crash

Comment: Exactly, even with 0, `setTimeout` queed first in the stack but still I don't get it how can't we **copy** any value? I expect at least we can copy the old one or the new one. If I were you I wouldn't accept my answer, too :) This is why I put a smiley there :) Also, I am going to favorite this question to check time to time if there will be a neat solution.